# Choice function for elementary embedding $j: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Work in ZF. Let $\lambda$ be strongly inaccessible. Let $\kappa$ be such that for every $\alpha\lt\lambda$, there is some $j: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda$, with critical point $\kappa$, such that $j(\kappa)\gt\alpha$.

> In this setting, can we define a sequence $A=\langle j_\alpha: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda\mid \alpha\lt\lambda\rangle$, such that every $j_\alpha$ is a non-trivial elementary embedding with critical point $\kappa$, and $j_\alpha(\kappa)\gt\alpha$?

(Note: $A$ needs to be a sequence, not just the set of all embeddings.)

**Motivation:** I was doing research on large cardinals without choice, and was attempting to use a similar collection of embedding to $A$ to give a first order definition of cardinals that were $n$-huge.

Comment: Can you show in ZF that the set $\{ j(cr(j)) | j : V_\lambda \to V_\lambda$ is elementary$\}$ is cofinal in $\lambda$, assuming it’s nonempty?

Comment: That is the definition of the problem. For any $\alpha$, we have that there is some $j: V_\lambda\prec V_\lambda$ with $j(crit(j))\gt\alpha$.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is the least inaccessible for which there is such an elementary embedding, then that set is not cofinal since $\lambda$ is not a limit of inaccessibles.

Comment: You're right. I assumed he was talking about this specific problem.

Comment: May we assume AC in $V_\kappa$ (and therefore also in $V_\lambda$)?

Comment: We cannot assume $AC$ in $V_\lambda$, because $(V_{\lambda+1},\in,V_\lambda)\vDash\kappa\text{ is Reinhardt}$. We therefore also cannot assume $AC$ in $V_\kappa$ (Because $V_\kappa\prec V_\lambda$).

Comment: Ah, I had missed your requirement that $\lambda$ is inaccessible.